# How to see tables created on SQL developer with SQL PLUS?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I created a tablespace on Oracle SQL Developer and trying to access tables data with SQL PLUS console. But when I insert a row with SQL Developer and want to see if the result is display on the SQL PLUS console, SQL PLUS doesn't show me any results. Seems like there's no connection between SQL PLUS and SQL Developer. 
Is anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Did you commit?

Answer (score 1):

of course you are committing the transactions, then querying them from SQL*Plus; otherwise there is no way to see the data from another session.

```
commit;
```

Comment: but where should I write the "commit;" line ?

Comment: I found :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: there's a COMMIT button in the main toolbar, or you can manually type 'commit' and run in a SQL Worksheet and run it - either way the transactions in SQL Developer on that connection will be COMMITTED - then you can see stuff in SQL*Plus or in any other tool/session for that matter

Comment: hey @thatjeffsmith !  Hope all is well with you.

Answer (score 0):

SQLDeveloper and SQL*Plus are just two front end tools that allow to access the database. Let's start by making sure, that:
* You connected with the same database
* You are connected as the same user
* You did commit

Comment: I am right connected to the database on both front end tools. But I didn't know that I have to commit changes. I am pretty new on Oracle Sql Developer :( So I don't know the tool's possibilities.

Comment: Thank you. That helped ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit from JDeveloper and not be in a transaction in sqlplus.